# How can I exclude a folder from a .NET installer for a website?

Tags: asp.net, installation

We have an installer for a website of ours which works great, I exclude the web.config and a few other files when creating the installer. However I can't seem to exclude a folder. Is this possible?

I've created the installer using the .NET built in Web Setup Project found in the visual studio group Other project types > Setup and Deployment within the new project dialog. This only has the option of including groups of output and excluding files via the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to exclude entire folders and any files within sub-directories was to modify the deployment project which fed into my Installer. Check out the following for information removing folders pre-build:

http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=137

And this for post-build:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/10/05/exclude-files-and-folders-from-wdp-output.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What technology are you using to generate your installer?

**Edit after additional info in the question:** OK, I haven't worked with the built in Web Setup Project, but I did use a regular setup project once. You control the output of each project that's included in the setup by setting the [Build Action property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) of each content file. Set it to None to exclude a file.

There isn't a Build Action property for a folder, so you'll have to set it for all the files within a folder. If a folder doesn't have any content files, then it shouldn't be included in your setup project.

Comment: Add more details into the qusetion Dennis.

Comment: I will try and get around to doing this soon Dennis then hopefully mark you're answer as accepted. I've been pulled off onto another project for now...

Comment: I've just tried this and it works perfectly for Visual Studio 2008. Thanks